# Looping in c vs. python

Tags: python, c, arrays, numpy

I have wrapped a C function `calculate_something` in Python. The function takes 3 floats, does some calculations, and returns 2 floats. I want to use this function on 3 arrays of floats. That is, for each index in the arrays, call `calculate_something` on the corresponding floats and store the outputs in two arrays to be returned. Will it be significantly faster to do the loop in C compared to doing the loop in Python, when all I do inside the loop is call the C function and store the value in a (pre-allocated NumPy) output array?

In other words, consider the following Python function:

```
def calculate_array(arr1, arr2, arr3):
    out1 = np.empty(len(arr1))
    out2 = np.empty(len(arr1))
    for i in range(len(arr1)):
        r1, r2 = my_c_lib.calculate_something(arr1[i], arr2[i] arr3[i])
        out1[i] = r1
        out2[i] = r2
```

Will I gain a significant speedup by doing this function in C instead of Python? (Forgive me my ignorance, I do not know any C and have simply managed to wrap a useful function in Python.)

Comment: Yes, though you might want to try to write this loop in cython to bring it (somewhat) up to  c speeds

Comment: Are you still going to be using numpy?

Comment: What does the function calculate? Perhaps there's a Python implementation.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Not sure exactly what you mean, but everything I'm doing with arrays in python is based on numpy.

Comment: @eddiewould magnetic coordinates (there's not).

Comment: If that is Python 2, `xrange()` will likely be faster, but why not use an iterator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer really depends on how expensive each `calculate_something` invocation is, and how many elements you're processing. If (for example) each invocation takes half a second then the overhead of calling from Python is going to be pretty insignificant.

On the other hand, if each invocation is measured in ns/ms (and you've got millons/billions of elements) then it might be worth worrying about the overhead of calling from Python (in which case, I'd ask why you're bothering to implement calculate_something in C in the first place).

Comment: Well, if it takes 1 ms in C and 10 i Python then that's a significant speedup, even though both are "some ms".

Comment: @cmeeren The computational speed is limited by the slowest part of the code. If the actual calculation take 1 s per loop, you don't care if it's going to be an additional 10 ms (arbitrary number)  overhead per loop in Python vs C, it's not going to change the overall execution time.

Comment: What I meant was that if each iteration, in total, takes 1 ms when looping in C and 10 ms when looping in Python, then that's a big difference even though both of them are measured in ms

Comment: @cmeeren - here's an example. Let's say the calculation time is fixed at 1s per iteration and there are 1000 elements. The total computation time is 1000s (~16 minutes). If the looping/calling overhead is 1ms then that adds 1 * 1000 = 1s, total execution time of 1001s (~16 minutes). If the looping/calling overhead is 10ms then that adds 10 * 1000 = 10s, total execution time of 1010s (~16 minutes). Surely you don't care about the difference between a program that takes 1001 seconds to run and a program that takes 1010 seconds to run?

Comment: No I fully understand your point. You were wondering why I was bothering to implement ``calculate_something`` in C in the first place if each invocation was measured in ms. That is what I tried to address in my comment. If ``calculate_something`` takes 1 ms in C and 10 ms in Python, then that is an order of magnitude faster in C even though both are measured in ms.

Comment: Ok - well that makes sense then :) PS If you really want to make it fly then you have what is called an "embarrassingly parallel" problem, meaning you can literally just divide the array into n jobs where n corresponds to the number of sockets you have available. You could look into the Python multiprocessing module, or even set up some form of distributed/grid computing.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you do some benchmarks to figure out the performance difference?

You can perform say, a million iterations of the function as is, with the C code embedded.

If you haven't written implementation in C, or let's say you already have, you can replace the implementation with a do nothing function.

Then write a similar do nothing function in Python, and perform a similar million iterations.

There are several ways you can profile an app, but one simple way to do it from unix would be to run your app with the time command, like so:

> time [your app.py]

time will then give you app run time statistics.

Using a do nothing function simply profiles the performance difference in terms of function call overheads between C and Python. There are of course potential performance difference due to the actual implementation itself which you can profile if you can implement the function in both languages.